# Is it possible to sort Email order confirmation by SKU

Tags: magento2, customer, vat, sort, confirmation

My website is on MAGENTO 2
Any time that a customer send an order I received an email confirmation with SKU, DESCRIPTION, PRICE.

But I need that this email report is sorted by SKU. is it possible?
is it also possible to put VAT NUMBER OF CUSTOMER in this email?

thanks.
TEOS

Comment: Yes, it is possible but for that, you need to apply some customization in Magento 2. You need to override the order collection code which passes data to the email template. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @Nits I need this code.

Comment: sorry I dont have code ready. I just provided the logic, how you will get it done.